# mysqldump Disable conversion of datetime

Tags: mysql

`mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD databasename > db.sql`

When process is completed. The dates in mysqldump convert into local timezone. How to prevent from converting dates. And remain the original date.

Comment: So your DB server timezone is UTC ? And are you importing the data back to a different DB locally or you saw the change in the .sql file ?

Comment: This typically happens for `timestamp` datatypes and you need to use the dump as `mysqldump -tz-utc=false -u root -pPASSWORD databasename > db.sql`  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tz-utc

Comment: My database time is in UTC format my server's time is in IST format, mysqldump converts date into IST format. how can i prevent it

Comment: `mysqldump --skip-tz-utc -u root ......`

Comment: thanks @AbhikChakraborty it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqldump --skip-tz-utc -u root -pPASSWORD databasename > db.sql`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tz-utc

Thankyou @Abhik